# sql distinct selection avg aggregate

Tags: sql

**here is my table schema**

[image: IMG]

SessionID and relevancy is **not** unique

i want to remove urlid duplicates and have an avg of relevancy values corresponding of each unique urlid.

**this is my code**

```
select distinct URLID,avg (Relevancy) from ccc 
group by URLID,Relevancy
```

**my result**

[image: IMG]

for example i want to have this for urlid=15030753
(2+0)/2=1

```
urlid         avg
 ...          ...
15030753      1
...           ...
```

Comment: Remove 'Relevancy' field from `group by`. Use `select distinct URLID,avg (Relevancy) from ccc 
group by URLID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `Relevancy` in the `GROUP BY` clause, if you want to aggregate over it. You can also drop the `DISTINCT` as there will be just one `URLID` entry due to the `GROUP BY`.

```
select URLID,avg (Relevancy) from ccc 
group by URLID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` with `URLID` only

```
SELECT URLID,avg(Relevancy) from ccc 
GROUP BY URLID
```

Check the following document for more details on how to use group by with average command
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx